# Xarray: ValueError: dimensions or multi-index levels ['lons', 'lats'] do not exist

Tags: python, python-3.x, netcdf, python-xarray

I'm trying to slice some netCDF data for climate projections and having some trouble with selecting the longitude and latitude values.

Here is what the dataset looks like.

```
In [49]: dataSet
Out[49]: 
<xarray.Dataset>
Dimensions:    (bnds: 2, time: 60, x: 253, y: 167)
Coordinates:
  * time       (time) object 2016-01-16 12:00:00 ... 2020-12-16 12:00:00
    lon        (y, x) float64 ...
    lat        (y, x) float64 ...
  * x          (x) float64 -6.3e+06 -6.25e+06 -6.2e+06 ... 6.25e+06 6.3e+06
  * y          (y) float64 -4.15e+06 -4.1e+06 -4.05e+06 ... 4.1e+06 4.15e+06
    height     float64 ...
Dimensions without coordinates: bnds
Data variables:
    time_bnds  (time, bnds) object ...
    tasmax     (time, y, x) float32 ...
    crs        |S1 ...
```

When I try to get temperature values from this data based on certain geographical coordinates I get this error.

```
In [50]: dataSet.sel(lon='71.560135', lat='34.025917', time='2018-07-01', method='nearest').data[0]

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-50-c0ee548ca1df>", line 1, in <module>
    dataSet.sel(lon='71.560135', lat='34.025917', time='2018-07-01', method='nearest').data[0]

  File "D:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\xarray\core\dataset.py", line 2006, in sel
    self, indexers=indexers, method=method, tolerance=tolerance

  File "D:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\xarray\core\coordinates.py", line 380, in remap_label_indexers
    obj, v_indexers, method=method, tolerance=tolerance

  File "D:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\xarray\core\indexing.py", line 259, in remap_label_indexers
    dim_indexers = get_dim_indexers(data_obj, indexers)

  File "D:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\xarray\core\indexing.py", line 225, in get_dim_indexers
    raise ValueError("dimensions or multi-index levels %r do not exist" % invalid)

ValueError: dimensions or multi-index levels ['lon', 'lat'] do not exist
```

The lat and lon values(arrays?) inside the data set look something like this

```
In [51]: dataSet.lat.values
Out[51]: 
array([[-25.2261467 , -25.13259315, -25.03960228, ..., -25.03960228,
        -25.13259315, -25.2261467 ],
       [-24.86881447, -24.77511597, -24.68197823, ..., -24.68197823,
        -24.77511597, -24.86881447],
       [-24.50981522, -24.41597176, -24.32268715, ..., -24.32268715,
        -24.41597176, -24.50981522],
       ...,
       [ 41.7208252 ,  41.83537292,  41.94952393, ...,  41.94952393,
         41.83537292,  41.7208252 ],
       [ 42.0737381 ,  42.1884079 ,  42.3026886 , ...,  42.3026886 ,
         42.1884079 ,  42.0737381 ],
       [ 42.42486954,  42.53966904,  42.65407944, ...,  42.65407944,
         42.53966904,  42.42486954]])

In [52]: dataSet.lon.values
Out[52]: 
array([[ 20.79260826,  21.18661499,  21.58048439, ..., 118.41951752,
        118.81338501, 119.20738983],
       [ 20.68895531,  21.08365822,  21.47822571, ..., 118.52177429,
        118.91634369, 119.31104279],
       [ 20.58544159,  20.98083687,  21.37609863, ..., 118.62390137,
        119.01916504, 119.41455841],
       ...,
       [  2.21267986,   2.68719077,   3.16272235, ..., 136.83728027,
        137.31280518, 137.787323  ],
       [  2.05844355,   2.53320289,   3.00899577, ..., 136.99099731,
        137.46679688, 137.94155884],
       [  1.90317976,   2.3781817 ,   2.85422993, ..., 137.14576721,
        137.62181091, 138.09681702]])
```

I'd really appreciate any help on this, I need to extract the data from either this or use non-downgraded models which might hamper the efficacy of my other results.

Comment: I'd try two things. First, try extract the relevant DataArray from the DataSet, so tasmax=dataSet['tasmax'], and then try the `.sel()` command as you have it. 

If that doesn't work then it *might* be to do with the fact that tasmax is actually indexed by 'x', and 'y', not 'latitude'/'longitude', although I'm less sure about this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.sel` requires dimension names rather than non-dimension coordinates. You could use `.where` to filter by coordinate values if needed

Comment: What if you want to find the nearest coordinate? .sel has the 'method = nearest' argument, but not .where

Answer (score 0):

Like Maximilian pointed out, `lon` and `lat` are non-dimension coordinates. The dimensions you can use in `.sel` of your dataset are `x`, `y` and `time`. So you have to calculate the `x` and `y` coordinates corresponding to your `lon` and `lat`. You can do this with the following code (not tested), approximately:

```
import numpy as np
# calculate distance (no sqrt as we are only interested in the location of the minimum)
d = ((dataset.lon - 71.560135) ** 2 + (dataset.lat - 34.025917) ** 2).values
row, col = np.unravel_index(np.argmin(d), d.shape)
dataSet.sel(x=dataset.x[col], y=dataset.y[row], time='2018-07-01', method='nearest')
```

We hereby make the mistake to use a distance calculation for a rectangular coordinate system on a spherical coordinate system, but we are approximately right. You can change the calculation of d if this bothers you.